# Why is there always a Householder transformation that maps one specific vector to another?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm wondering why, if I'm given two vectors $u$ and $v$, I can always find a Householder transformation that maps $u$ to $v$. (This is needed in QR factorisation with Householder transformations).

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Householder transformation is a *reflection* about a plane. That is, under a suitable orthonormal basis $\{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n\}$, a Householder transformation $H$ is simply the linear transformation defined by $Hw_1=-w_1$ and $Hw_j=w_j$ for $j>1$. It follows that every Householder transformation is a unitary matrix that preserves norms of vectors. So, your statement is *not* true if $u$ and $v$ have different lengths.

Now, given two vectors $u$ and $v$ of the same norm, let $P$ be a two-dimensional plane containg them. Let $w_2\in P$ be a unit vector that is an angle bisector of $u$ and $v$ (i.e. $w_2=\frac{u+v}{\|u+v\|}$ if $u,v$ are nonzero, or $w_2$ is any unit vector if $u=v=0$) and $w_1\in P$ be a unit vector that is orthogonal to $w_2$. Extend $\{w_1,w_2\}$ to an orthonormal basis $\{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n\}$. Then the Householder transformation we previously defined will map $u$ to $v$. You may draw a picture to visualize this.